# Como salvar os dados de um model outro. Para arquivar informações

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho dois models: funcionários e relatórios. Todos os mêses algumas informações sobre os funcionários sofrem alterações enquanto outras permanecem iguais. Quero criar relatórios com as informações mês a mês. Assim se quiser saber quanto um funcionário recebeu em determinado mês basta acessar o relatório daquele funcionário naquele mês. Estou tentando criar essa funcionalidade usando accept next attributes. E o correto? Estou com dificuldades para criar o form de relatório na página show de funcionário. Tem jeito né? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: "criar o form" na página "show de funcionário" não sei se é necessário, por convenção formulários ficam na view "new.html.erb", mas se é isso que deseja, um formulário na mesma página em que apresenta as informações do usuário, o formulário é criado da mesma forma.

Ademais, você precisa de um relacionamento do tipo has_many entre o funcionário e o relatório (um funcionário tem vários relatórios).

```
#app/controllers/offices_controller.rb
class OfficesController < ApplicationController  
  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id]) # Aqui você está pegando o funcionário
    @report = Report.new # Aqui você cria uma nova instância de um objeto Report
  end
end

# app/views/offices/show.html.erb
<%= @employee.name %>
<%= @employee.age %>
<%= @employee.salary %>

<%= form_for(@report) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :employee_id, value: @employee.id %>
  <%= f.text_field :salary, value: @employee.salary %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/reports_controller.rb
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Report.create(report_params)
  end

  private

  # Aqui é a validação do Strong Parameters, para uma validação que se encaixe
  # com suas necessidades consulte a documentação:
  # https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters
  def report_params
    params.fetch(:report).permit!
  end
end
```

Comment: Legal cara, na verdade eu estava complicando sem necessidade. Todo mês apenas os dados referentes ao holerite mudam. Então eu criei um novo model holerite associei a funcionários. Assim no lugar de relatórios fiz @funcionario.relatorios.each do |h| h.data enes e assim tenho as informações relativas à quando cada um recebeu em determinado mês. Agora estou enroscado em uma besteira aqui. Como faço pra colocar link em cada holerite listado no each acima? link_to h.data, funcionario_holerite_path não funciona.

Comment: <= link_to "relatório", report_path(report) %>. Só um detalhe, quando alguém te ajudar em uma resposta, de um `upvote`. Assim, seguiremos as convenções do StackOverflow.

Comment: Quase isso, mas nas rotas report está dentro de funcionário . Awe não funciona. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Desculpe, sou novo aqui mas vou fazer o que pediu. Agradeço a ajuda. O codigo ainda não esta funcionando. Vou tentar explicar melhor. Tenho dois models Funcionarios e Holerites. Dai fiz o has_many e o belogns_to e essa parte ta funcionando. Na pagina show de Funcionario eu fiz um loop com each: <% @funcionario.holerites.each do |holerite| %> <p><%= link_to holerite.data, holerite_path(holerite) %></p> <% end %>